# Is it possible to create a new 8gig partition as installer in lion

Tags: macos, mac

is it possible to create, let's say 8gig partition in your HD and create an installer just like having it created in usb to dvd, so that I can do a clean re install Mac OS Lion?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a clean reinstall from the recovery partition without needing any external media:

- Hold command-R on startup
- Erase the Macintosh HD volume from Disk Utility
- Choose Reinstall OS X

If you don't erase the OS X volume first, Reinstall OS X does an upgrade install.

See [OS X Lion: Erase and reinstall Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph4439).

"Startup disk" probably means the main OS X volume (like Macintosh HD) here:

> Select your startup disk from the list on the left, and then click the Erase tab.

If you erase the whole drive, it also erases the recovery partition and EFI partition, and your Mac will try to start up in [internet recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) mode when it is restarted.

Comment: The HD/USB partition is useful if you want to restore to an (older) specific version of OSX.  Apple only lets you restore the newest version of each major release (so, currently 10.7.5 and 10.8.3).  It also doesn't require an internet connection.